# How to store special charaters in MySQL - [AîA]

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, utf-8, greasemonkey

I am wondering how I would go about storing this in MySQL

I am storing it by posting it from a greasemonkey script to php to insert it into a MySQL database.

So far `[AîA]` turns into `[AÃ®A]`

this is part of my post function:

```
GM_xmlhttpRequest({
    method: "POST",
    url: URL + "Script/player.php",
    data: LoginUrl,

    headers: {
        "User-Agent":"Update Script",
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    },
```

I think I might need to change the Content type too UTF-8 but when I tried this it broke the script. I also tried using:

```
encodeURIComponent(Name)
```

But this didn't work properly or was broken because of not setting header properly.

Comment: Can you isolate the problem and tell at the PHP level (taking mysql out) if the data you submit is already broken or not? Can you specify the encoding the data is in?

Comment: I can set it in headers as UTF-8 but when I tried it broke. I think I just did it wrong is all.

Comment: Put MySQL aside for trouble shooting. w/o Mysql, which encoding of the input data do you have?

Comment: I was missing this from php file:mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");

Comment: Use [`mysql_set_charset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php) instead, it *"is the preferred way to change the charset. Using mysql_query() to execute SET NAMES .. is not recommended."* - and please add your final solution as an answer below. You can accept it then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the PHP file that submits the information into the database I had to set the charset using

```
mysql_set_charset()
```

Final connection code:

```
$conn = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
mysql_select_db($db, $conn);
mysql_set_charset('utf8',$conn);
```

Thanks Hakre for answer.