# Issue when inserting UTF8 characters in db from script

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, insert

I have a small script that receive some data through GET and inserts data in a db. My problem is when sending some UTF-8 characters. The scritp receives them ok but inserts them in a weird way. I printed the query in my page, executed it with phpmyadmin and works ok that way. So, my problem is when executing the query through my script (it doesn't work if I execute a constant query with those characters). Does sending characters by post resolve the issue?

Thank you

Comment: You need to specify the encoding for your Mysql connection. Depending on the mysql extension you use, the name of the function can vary: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php

Comment: Give more information. "In a weird way" is not useful. Ideally, provide hexdumps of the actual bytes transmitted or stored, not just textual cut-and-pastes from terminal windows.

Comment: An answer in this possible duplicate [How to store special charaters in MySQL - \[AîA\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6984530/how-to-store-special-charaters-in-mysql-aia) formulates it more nicely.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
mysql_set_charset('utf8');
```

Comment: Better use `mysql_set_charset()` instead of `SET NAMES`

Comment: The main advantage of `mysql_set_charset()` is that it is safer.

Answer (score 0):

Your entire setup has to be UTF-8. That means your web page, PHP, the database connection, AND the database tables, all have to be in UTF-8 mode. Given it works in the admin pages and not via script, I'm guessing it's your database connection. Try doing a `set names='utf-8'` before doing your insert query, and see if that fixes things. If it does, then your db connection is using some OTHER character set and mangling your text as it goes from PHP->database.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in the php file before your query:

```
mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8');
```

For example:

```
//DB connection
$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');//db details
if (!$con){
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("mydatabase", $con);//DB name
mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8');
//query
$sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid=".$user_id;// your query
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: Better use `mysql_set_charset()` instead of `SET NAMES`